# Is there any use for the new HK-51 gear that was mailed if yours already came with gear?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I understand that some people got a "naked" HK due to a bug, but mine came wearing a full set of Orange gear with blue 51 mods.  Does the "HK-51's Combat Outfit" that was mailed today with patch 1.5.2 contain exactly the same items?  It's BoL so I don't want to open it if I'll need it for an alt.  (Are the items inside it BoP, BoL, or BoE?  Do they sell for much?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bag it came in is bound to legacy, so you can transfer it to another character. That way you can send the bag to a low level toon you buy HK-51 for, then just replace the mods in his current gear with low level ones. If you hang onto said bag of gear you open it when you're 50 and you're set, not having to consume many bank spaces with gear you can't use.

Comment: Ah so if you buy HK-51 you don't get endgame gear in the mail for him?  Do you still get it if you acquire him the usual way on a lvl 50 alt?

Comment: I bought HK at lvl 1 and he came with his lvl 50 gear. just the same as if I had found him with my lvl 50.

Comment: @Matt Interesting, I assume the 50 gear is separate and not equippable?  Was it the same "Combat Outfit" bag?